# Finding Corresponding "X" value for the maximum deviation between two columns in two different text files

Tags: awk

I have two files with N number of columns and a header in the first line (Same column headers for both files).

```
File1:
    Header e   f    g ...... N
    1.0    1   2    3 ...... N1
    2.0    2   2    7 ...... N1
    3.0    5   3    3 ...... N1

File2:
    Header  e   f    g ...... N
    1.0     2   2    4 ...... N2
    2.0     1   9    4 ...... N2
    3.0     12  3    6 ...... N2


I want 1st column value from File1 will be subtracted (absolute value) from 1st 
column of File2, and this way till column N as shown below:


    Header  e   f    g ...... N  
    1.0     1   0    1 ...... N1-N2 
    2.0     1   7    3 ...... N1-N2
    3.0     7   0    3 ...... N1-N2
```

Then for each column I need to find out the maximum values and corresponding header value.

For example for `column e` maximum value is 7 and that corresponds to `Header value 3`.

```
The actual desired output given that input Header value = { 3.0, 2.0, 3.0 Or 2.0 }
```

So far I can only subtracted the column values and store them in a file. (I still have issue with printing the header)

````
awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[FNR"-"i]=$i;next}{printf "\n"$1" ";}
FNR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf $i-a[FNR"-"i]" "}}' File01.txt File02.txt | column -t -s' '> subtracted_data.txt```
````

Comment: `NR==1{savedHdr=$0}` ? Or do you want/need to allow for skipping columns in the output? Good luck.

Comment: It can be done with awk but python is more suitable for this job. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I am not that familiar with python.

Comment: @EdMorton awk is a specialized language and is good for something quick. python is a general purpose language which I think is more suitable for something as complex as what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ paste file1 file2 | 
  awk 'function abs(x) {return x<0?-x:x}                                                                                  
       NR>1 {n=NF/2; 
             for(i=2;i<=n;i++) 
               {v[i]=abs($i-$(i+n)); 
                if(v[i]>max[i]) {max[i]=v[i]; maxIx[i]=$1}}} 
       END {printf "{";
            for(i=2;i<n;i++) printf "%s, ",maxIx[i]
            print maxIx[n]"}"}'

{3.0, 2.0, 2.0}
```

combine files with `paste` to simplify processing.

compute each absolute value, find the max and corresponding max index and print them at the end.

Comment: Thanks. But the column numbers are not known. As your awk script fit only for 4 columns.

Comment: it's easy to make it to work for any number of columns, and I did.

Comment: It would be great if you add some explanation for the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One of the plethora of possibilities is:

```
awk '(NR==1){ print }    # print header
     (FNR==1){ next }    # skip header
     # read file1 in memory
     # store full line with key $1
     (NR==FNR) { a[$1]=$0; next }
     # read file2 and
     # request file1 value by key, and split in array b
     { split(a[$1],b) }
     # perform magic
     { for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) $i-=b[i] }
     { print }' file1 file2
```

This is not the most optimal solution but probably will do the trick.

Comment: @kvantour that was a silly mistake from my side, however how can i print only absolute values. Thanks

Comment: Great, I make an abs function and call it later. It worked. Thanks